# Difference Between Two TimeStamps

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a large dataset in MySQL ordered by timestamp that contains missing gaps and I am trying to fill the gaps in between minutes with the data from the previous timestamp. An example of what I'm trying to accomplish is:

```
2013-10-04 13:51:00

2013-10-04 13:50:00

2013-10-04 13:48:00

2013-10-04 13:47:00

2013-10-04 13:46:00
```

Where the gap is between 13:48:00 and 13:50:00, I'd like to insert a row for 13:49:00 with the data from 13:48:00. Is this possible using just a MySQL query? If so what would the query look like?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than duplicating your data, why not adjust your SELECT query? Something like this would work:

```
SELECT * FROM `tableName` WHERE `timestampColumn` <= '2013-10-04 13:49:00'
                                             ORDER BY `timestampColumn` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Make sure you index the `timestampColumn` to ensure good performance. In this example, it will find the "missing" data by looking for the data immediately preceding it. This also means you can query any time at all, not just exact minutes.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and this is a great idea however the data is being used in a separate application that requires no gaps, so I'm trying to iterate through all the dates filling the gaps between minutes.